# Persisting SplashScreen until react native bundle is loaded in android

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen, android-inflate

I followed android guide in this article [How to Add a Splash Screen to a React Native App](https://medium.com/handlebar-labs/how-to-add-a-splash-screen-to-a-react-native-app-ios-and-android-30a3cec835ae)

And got to the point where I have my SplashScreen activity launching before my main activity i.e. while android app is inflating.

So far so good, but there is flicker of white that is caused by react native js bundle loading that I'd like to remove. Article suggests using `react-native-splash-screen` library, however I'd like to keep my dependencies to a minimum.

React native documentation has this [Pro Tip](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html#pro-tip) that essentially achieves what I am looking for, but in iOS (it keeps showing splash screen while bundle is not loaded). I am trying to figure out how I would do something similar in native java for android, but so far no luck.

Comment: Using the pro tip stops working once you do some async work (eg. loading some persisted state upon startup) - the component loads and splash goes away, but your app won't show anything until it loads the state. That is why you need some better solution that will control the splash from JS. You will end up using some dependency for that, just note that the ios implementation of react-native-splash-screen is bad (https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen/blob/master/ios/SplashScreen.m#L30). If you're interested, I have a fork that has a nicer solution. I may contribute it back.

Comment: @vonovak I see, would love to see the fork if possible. At present I don't have any async actions on startup, hence don't see this issue I guess.

Comment: @vonovak but would still like an answer demonstrating how this can be done in native java if possible

Comment: I already have what you are looking for android and I used the same article to implement the splash screen without any white screen. have a look on [this repo](https://github.com/Shhzdmrz/SplashTest)

Comment: @ShahzadMirza checked out your example, you seem to be doing standard approach using `react-native-splash-screen` correct? I am looking to avoid this dependency and implement this via native code i.e. like iOS example I linked (it doesn't use `react-native-splash-screen`) But I can't figure out how to find out if bundle has loaded from java code so I can then hide the SplashScreen.

Comment: yes, I am using same package and before I was looking for same answer as you were but problem occured when I have to fetch data after bundle load and so now my time exceeded to show splash screen until the data loaded. That's the reason I used it this package. if you just want to get the info of bundle load in java then I think the package code that I'm using will be helpful.

Comment: @Ilja I do not think the ios functionality has an  android equivalent. My fork is here but there is some custom android code which is not nice :D https://github.com/vonovak/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: @ShahzadMirza was looking through your source, any chance you could point me to the file that checks bundle load info? I can't see anything like this atm inside main/java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here a way to do it when content is added by React:

```
=== MainActivity.java ===

import com.facebook.react.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {
    class CustomReactActivityDelegate extends ReactActivityDelegate {
        class CustomReactRootView extends ReactRootView {
            public CustomReactRootView(Context context) {
                super(context);
            }
            @Override
            public void onViewAdded(View child) {
                 super.onViewAdded(child);
                 Log.d("React views started to appear", "Static js code has already run");
            }
        }
        private Activity currentActivity;
        public CustomReactActivityDelegate(Activity activity, String mainComponentName) {
            super(activity, mainComponentName);
            currentActivity = activity;
        }
        protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
            return new CustomReactRootView(currentActivity);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new CustomReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName());
    }
    ...
}
```

As you can see, the idea is to override stuff to hook into needed moment.

You could see other stuff to hook into in those classes, but in general react loads bundle asynchronously with jni functions, so I am not sure there's much to do there. You could override a chain

1. `MainApplication` (assign `mReactNativeHost`) ->
2. `ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager` (copy original method but call `ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.setJSBundleLoader`) ->
3. `JSBundleLoader` (wrap original `JSBundleLoader.createAssetLoader` into custom subclass, which would call inner loader in `loadScript` and then also call `CatalystInstanceImpl.callFunction`) ->
4. `CatalystInstanceImpl.PendingJSCall` to just run what you need to run in there.

In other words, it's horrible and still React does not guarantee that `PendingJSCall` won't be run before bundle loads.

Answer (score -1):

Use [rn-splash-scren](https://github.com/mehcode/rn-splash-screen). When your react component loads, just call

> import SplashScreen from "rn-splash-screen";
>
> // Hide the active splash screen
>
> SplashScreen.hide();

You need to set it up from the native side but that is easy.

Comment: This is similar to using `react-native-splash-screen` package mentioned in question, which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: any reason why not?

Comment: Reduce reliance on js bridges for small things like these.